# Form Input to Session Variable

Tags: php, html, session-variables

First question I have is that I would like on the index.php to ask the user a question via a form and when the press submit it updates the session variable on jcart.php. With the current code below when I call the session variable later on it is now found so I assume the code I have just now is not working correctly.

The second question is when I press submit it takes me to jcart.php is there a way to avoid this or have it go back.

On my index.php I have a form :

```
<form action="jcart/jcart.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="example" id="example" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And on Jcart.php :

```
$_SESSION['example'] = $_POST['example'];
```

Then on the page I am calling it on cocktails.php

```
<?php 
include_once('jcart/jcart.php');
session_start();
?>

<input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['example'];?>" />
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: session_start(); should be call in jcart.php, then only you can assign the session values

Comment: Are you calling `session_start`?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the comments this code is actually part of a script called Jcart, there doesnt seem to be support for it anymore so turning to Stackoverflow. I assume session start is working because the cart as a whole works.

I can store a session variable in jcart.php by hard coding it and it works, I just seem to add it dynamically.

With regards to calling session start first line :

// If your page calls session_start() be sure to include jcart.php first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to "**update the session variable on jcart.php**". Once you store a data into the global $_SESSION array, it should be available on all php files, at least until you destroy the session.

That being said, if jcart/jcart.php needs to have a `$_SESSION['example']` variable, you need to be sure, that the session is started before including the file, for instance:

```
<?php 
    session_start()
    include_once('jcart/jcart.php');
?>
```

For your other question, you can change the action inside your form to whatever you like or issue a `header('Location: /');` to redirect to other page after the value was recieved.

Comment: Hey thanks the first part still isnt workin but the redirect is now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
*jcart.php*

session_start();
$_SESSION['example'] = $_POST['example'];

*then cocktails.php*

include_once('jcart/jcart.php');

echo $_SESSION['example'];
```

Comment: Hey gave this a try, doesn't seem to work though. Just tried to echo in to a <p></p> but nothing is showing

Comment: Sorry just looked up print_r, beyond me. I am used to just hacking away. I will have to rethink this.

Answer (score 0):

in jcart/jcart.php

```
session_start();
```

should be called at the beginning